# safe url with .htaccess and moderewrite

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, mode

hi guy its my first time here and my english sukcs, sorry...
i have a problem with my .htaccess, i'm trying to redirect a page with a safe url using this code:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^noticias/pagina/([0-9]+)/?$ news.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
```

but my swf files called by nes.php does not open...

can someone help me?
who can i fix this problem?

my swf file are in the same folder as my file news.php....

Comment: Welcome to SO. Can you show a path to a SWF file that is not getting opened? It's impossible to tell from the htaccess file's contents what is wrong.

Comment: here:

<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="rodape.swf" width="960" height="45">

Answer (score 1):

This is probably an issue with wrong references to your resources. Since you’re now using a different URL (`/noticias/pagina/…`), relative URL paths are now resolved from this base instead of your old (`/news.php`). A reference `rodape.swf` is now resolved to `/noticias/pagina/rodape.swf`.

Try to reference your SWF file with an absolute URL path:

```
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="/rodape.swf" width="960" height="45">
```

Comment: one more time sorry for my english :S